# Missing SSL certificate cause unwanted redirect to another website

Tags: https, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a website without SSL certificate. When opened in browser it shows error message: "Potential Security Risk Ahead" which is good but when click "accept the risk and continue" then the website redirect to another website. I have found that this redirection is caused by browser pulling first avaliable SSL certificate from server which is created for different domain. I am using Nginx and Laravel Forge service and Let's Encrypt.

How do I turn this off? How does certificate for another domain ends up pulled by browser? I suposes this is caused by Nginx or Let's Encrypt configuration.

Comment: "browser pulling first avaliable SSL certificate from server which is created for different domain." browser is not pulling anything. browser is receiving a certificate sent by the server. So it is up to the server configuration to define which certificate to send when. It is 100% under control of the server.

Comment: "I have a website without SSL certificate." Your problem is probably there. More and more browsers become configured with "HTTPS first" or even "HTTPS only". So they will first try with HTTPS. You can't control that. You can however nowadays very easily, and for free, add a certificate to any website, so that should be your first step. Other than that you are not giving any details, nor the name tested, nor details on the browser (name, version), nor details on the webserver (name, version, configuration), etc. so it is hard to answer you.

Comment: I have dig a little bit more and found out that default Laravel Forge Nginx configuration ignores this situation and the correct solution is to just make SSL certificate. However I don't like that incorrectly configured site makes redirect to something random at least from users perspective. As you have point out I could configurate Nginx that it does return something else than default (first) certificate.

Comment: I recommend making your first virtual host return an error code for a dummy post names such as localhost.  Then your real domain name should each have their own later virtual host and anything unexpected falls back to an error code.

Answer (score 2):

(I use Apache, and I assume NGINX is similar in this regard)

I don't believe you CAN turn this off. Its not so much the browser pulling the first available SSL certificate as much as the server not knowing how to find the configuration for the domain in question, so falling back to the default host which happens to be the first entry.   Once it has the default entry the server presents the certificate associated with that entry.

The easiest solution would be to get a valid SSL certificate associated with the Virtualhost you want.  If for some reason you don't want to do that, you could, I guess, create a self signed certificate and associate it with the Virtualhost for your site.

Comment: "as the server not knowing how to find the configuration for the domain in question" This would happen only with very very old clients, because now all browsers use SNI which gives the name (of website) wanted early in the TLS handshake so outside of any server misconfiguration (or a name not configured at all) or a very old browser, the correct certificate is always returned.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It sounds like the name is not configured for HTTPS, even though it is configured for HTTP in this case.  That would cause the HTTPS request to fall back to the first configured HTTPS virtual host.